# Usar curl corretamente para direcionamento via post

Tags: php

Colegas.

Já tentei de tudo, usei meu código e busquei na internet, porém não sei mais o que fazer. Preciso fazer com que o usuário do sistema, ao acessar um determinado link, abra um outro site já logado. Via POST através da CURL. Meu último código segue abaixo e está retornando código 200. Quando uso o usuário e senha abaixo diretamente pelo site, ele consegue se logar, mas quando tento pelo nosso sistema, dá esse erro que informei:

```
$params = array(
        'usuario' => 'teste.usuario',
        'senha' => '123456'
);
$camposStrings = '';
 foreach($params as $key=>$valores){
    $camposStrings .= $key.'='.$valores.'&';    
}
$camposStrings .= rtrim($camposStrings, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.siteparceiro.com.br/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($camposStrings));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $camposStrings);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Ta retornando codigo 200 no site que voce precisa?

Comment: olá tkmattos. Ele dá o código 200, porém nada abre. Fica em branco.

Comment: de um print na variavel $output e veja o que esta sendo retornado. O codigo 200 esta falando que o que link que voce chamou esta respondendo